# Using map() function as a Future

Tags: flutter, dart

I want this map function to be executed before returning the value from the function. I tried using **Future.wait** but the if check makes the body null.
So, **I just used a print** statement and it worked like a breeze. It doesn't seem like the best solution though.
Please suggest a better approach for the same.

```
List<Student> foo(){
int i = -1;
  print(
    studentDataMap.values.map(
      (entry) {
        i++;
        if (studentIds.contains(entry['id'])) {
          studentsList.add(Student.fromRTDB(
              entry as Map, studentDataMap.keys.elementAt(i)));
        }
      },
    ),
  );
 return studentsList;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you call `.toList()` before `map`: `studentDataMap.values.toList().map(....)`?

Comment: instead of  `studentDataMap.values.map` use `studentDataMap.values.forEach`